# Facebook login button missing at in-app browsers

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, facebook-login

I'm having problem with showing FB login button in in-app browser at facebook and Instagram on Android and iOS.
Here is test code at CodePen https://codepen.io/Casperovsky/pen/OJXqjdb

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v9.0&appId=XXX&autoLogAppEvents=1" nonce="XXX"></script>
<b>test</b><br>
<div class="fb-login-button" data-size="large" data-button-type="continue_with" data-layout="default" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="true" data-width=""></div>
```

Everything is working fine in all major browsers like Chrome, Safari, Edge, Firefox, only problem is in in-app browsers in these applications.
Code is from Fb developers page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/login-button
I made some seperated tests with iframes, localstorage but it seems to everything works fine with that.
Intresting is that Fb demo at developers page is showing correctly. So I think I'm missing something, but I can't figure it out what.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. In Facebook application settings Website address doesn't matched one where I was testing.

Comment: What do you mean? The in-app browsers use the same URL no?